# How to add a common button in nav bar in all view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, navbar

I want to add/remove button in navbar as subview in all view controllers in my app. How do I move this add/remove to a common code so that I've less work to do to update my existing code to implement this feature?

I'm aware that I can add add/remove functions in `UIViewController` extension and then call it from each and every VC however this will require all my existing code to be updated.

Is there any other simpler way?

```
var condition: Bool = false

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Add button in navbar
        if condition {
            self.addTopButton()
        } else {
            self.removeTopButton()
        }
    }

    func addTopButton() {
        // create a button programatically and add it as subview in navbar
    }

    func removeTopButton() {
        // remove top button
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a parent view controller for all class needs the buttons.

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController {
    var condition: Bool = false

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Add button in navbar
        if condition {
            self.addTopButton()
        } else {
            self.removeTopButton()
        }
    }

    func addTopButton() {
        // create a button programatically and add it as subview in navbar
    }

    func removeTopButton() {
        // remove top button
    }
}
```

Other classes can inherit it and can also override the methods.

```
class MyViewController: ParentViewController {
    override func addTopButton() {
        // can choose to override method or not 
    }
}
```